# How do I read data in sub-dictionary in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

My problem is that I cannot see the data I pulled from the mongo database separately. The data comes as a dictionary and when I try to read it with pandas, it returns the sub dictionary group as a single data.

```
import pandas

dic = {
    "value1" : "a",
    "value2" : {
        "subvalue1" : "sub-a",
        "subvalue2" : "sub-b"
    },
    "value3" : "c"
}
df = pandas.DataFrame(dic)
df = pandas.DataFrame(list(dic.items()), columns=["value1","subvalue1"])
print(df)
```

When I run the code, the output I get is as follows.

```
   value1                                     subvalue1
0  value1                                             a
1  value2  {'subvalue1': 'sub-a', 'subvalue2': 'sub-b'}
2  value3                                             c

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What I want is I want to produce an output with the values in the "columns" array by writing a code like the one below.

```
import pandas

dic = {
    "value1" : "a",
    "value2" : {
        "subvalue1" : "sub-a",
        "subvalue2" : "sub-b"
    },
    "value3" : "c"
}
df = pandas.DataFrame(dic)
df = pandas.DataFrame(list(dic.items()), columns=["value1","subvalue1","subvalue2","value3"])
print(df)
```

output sample I want

[image: output sample]

How can i do this.
Thank you for all.

Comment: please don't leave questions hanging, if the answer is right please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, update your question to better reflect your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by flattening the dictionary like this:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    flattened={}
    for key, val in d.items():
        if isinstance(val,dict):
            flattened.update(flatten_dict(val))
        else:
            flattened.update({key:val})
    return flattened
```

I don't recommend this way however. If you happen to have a dictionary of the form `{"a":{"same_key_name":"value_a"}, "b":{"same_key_name":"value_b"}}` then the flattened dictionary would be `{'same_key_name': 'value_b'}`

A safer and more canonical way to do it is to flatten the dictionary but keep the key names in a concatenated form:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d, sep='_')
```